# Java: Last access of 2D HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the following structure:

> HashMap< String, HashMap< String, String>>

Now i want to know the last accessed element in the 2nd dimension.

I know there is TreeMap which makes sense in the 1rst dimension but after that it doesn't make any sense.

How can I keep track of a 2D HashMap ordering?

With access i mean:

> value = hashmap.get("a").get("1")
>
> value = hashmap.get("b").get("2")
>
> value = hashmap.get("c").get("3")
>
> hashmap.removeLast();
>
> hashmap.removeLast();
>
> hashmap.removeLast();

Comment: what do you mean with "last accessed"?

Comment: I updated the question accordingly

Comment: So you want to reorder the second map based on access time?

Comment: do you need the HashMap or did you just google around and found HashMap instead of **Array**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no native way to do what you want. But you can extends HashMap, override the get to store the key of the get in a list, and then add a method like removeLastGetElemet(), that just get the last element of the list and call a remove(key)

Comment: Ok, so what do you think will it be more memory consuming to just implement a LinkedList type of ordering or have a seperate List with the key pairs?

Comment: the best way is using a LinkedList<Sting> (it is a Queue, so element order of insertion is respected) where every element is the get's key. if you always add new key to head (addFirst), then you can remove the last used element just with map.remove(list.poll()), that way the list will auto-remove the deleted key from itself.

Comment: Ok, I didn't want to go this way, but if there is no other way thanks for your help.